# Add a variable to the end of an link within a leaflet map geoJSON popup

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I have a leaflet map with popups generated from a geoJSON file.  I am trying to create a link within the popup which has a unique URL based on the geoJSON properties.description entry associated with each popup. Anyone have an idea of how to do this correctly?

I have tried, as you can see below, saving the desired properties field to a variable call node along with several other iterations of saving this as a variable to call up in my  tag.

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([32.72, -117.16], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mapbox.streets',
}).addTo(mymap);

function addDataToMap(data, mymap) {
  var dataLayer = L.geoJSON(data, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
      var node = feature.properties.description;
      layer.bindPopup('<p>node id: '+feature.properties.description+'</p><p>node name: '+feature.properties.name+'</p>'+'<a href=https://server.herokuapp.com/+feature.properties.description+>''View Current Data''</a>');

    }
  }).addTo(mymap);
}

$.getJSON("https://server.herokuapp.com/locations", function(data) { addDataToMap(data, mymap); });
```

I would like to have the link within each popup open a new webpage that is unique based on the properties.description geoJSON field associated with each popup. In plain English I want a link with the following https://server.herokuapp.com/ + the string contained in my node variable.

Comment: Check your quotes, it looks like a simple syntax error.

Comment: Thank you!  That simple error had me tied up for hours.